# Этимология слова "приспичило"

Tags: этимология

"Приспичило" — значит "нужно безотлагательно". А при чем тут спички?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не спички, а "спичить" - в основе древний морф со значением "колоть". Отсюда же и "спица".

Comment: Ну, и как объяснить слово 'приспичить', исходя из смысла 'колоть' или 'спица'? Я просто интересуюсь...

Comment: Интересуйтесь, я не против.

Comment: И хочется, и колется...(я про "приспичило") Такая вот возникла ассоциация.

Comment: Нет, не думаю. Скорее уж "укололо - задергался". Как жареный петух, который тоже всегда вовремя клюнет.

ЗЫ Вот тихушника Виктора пока не клюнуло - он и минусует. Сначала grumant'а минусовал, тот на меня срывался, теперь вот лично уважил. Приспичило. )))

Comment: То есть приспичило=прикололо, пригвоздило к месту?

Comment: "Приспичило" — это значит, что появилась **острая** (в смысле сильная) и часто **рез**кая (то есть внезапная) нужда в чём-то.

Answer (score 0):

Иные версии:

ПРИСПИЧИЛО — образовано от слова «спички», синоним выражения «припекло». Тебя бы угораздило опять попасть в халепу, если бы не приспичило пойти на работу? …   Большой полутолковый словарь одесского языка

приспичить — чит; св. кому, с инф. безл.; разг. Срочно понадобиться. Приспичило покурить

Answer (score 0):

<<ПРИСПИЧИЛО>> это по своей первоисходной сути словцо *неприличное* . По-болгарски <<ПИЧКИ>>  это мужские яичники . Просто в русской речи это нехорошее старославянское  слово преобразовалось в более привычное <<**С**ПИЧКИ>> .  Ну , а смысловая ассоциация типа , как  чрезмерное половое возбуждение , которое требует немедленно заполучить полового партнёра . В общем , это по происхождению  *непристойный сленг* , но уже давно-давно мало , кто знает болгарский мат , сохранившийся в старорусском говоре .